# Half-reverse operation on binary strings

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

Is there an algorithm that you can apply *twice* to an input string of $0$s and $1$s in order to reverse it?

In other words, is there a function $f : \mathrm B \to \mathrm B$ on the set of binary strings $\mathrm B = \{\varepsilon, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, ...\}$ so that $f(f(b)) = \mathrm{reverse}(b)$ for all $b \in \mathrm B$?

If so, describe such a function/algorithm. If not, prove why it doesn’t exist.

(**BONUS**: for which other positive integers $n$ is there an algorithm that reverses a string when applied $n$ consecutive times?)

Comment: It holds for all odd $n$ with $f(b) = reverse(b)$ :-)

Comment: Impossible, by the way, for all even $n$ if $f(b)$ must have the same length as $b$, as seen from $f(01)$ or $f(10)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the set of binary strings that are lexicographically earlier than their reverses. For example, `011`, `1011`, and `11010111` are all members of this set, because `011` is earlier than `110`, `1011` is earlier than `1101`, and `11010111` is earlier than `11101011`. We can order this set by length, followed by lexicographical order. Let the first member (`01`) be $c_1$, the second member (`001`) be $c_2$, the third member (`011`) be $c_3$, and so on. Let $d_i=\text{reverse}(c_i)$.

For an integer $n$, define $f_n$ as follows:

- For every integer $i$ not a multiple of $n$, $f_n(c_i)=c_{i+1}$ and $f_n(d_i)=d_{i+1}$.
- For every integer $i$ that is a multiple of $n$, $f_n(c_i)=d_{i+1-n}$ and $f_n(d_i)=c_{i+1-n}$.
- Otherwise, $f_n(b)=b$.

When $f_n$ is applied $n$ times, the result is the reverse of the input:

- $f_n^{(n)}(c_i)=d_i$
- $f_n^{(n)}(d_i)=c_i$
- $f_n^{(n)}(b)=b$ for all $b$ that are not a $c_i$ or a $d_i$; the only such strings are the ones that are neither earlier than nor later than their reverses, so they are the same as their reverses.

Comment: Are there some extra $f_n$'s in the description of $f_n$? Otherwise, looks like a solid answer!

Comment: Aha, I see, so you are basically mapping the binary sequences to $\mathbb{N}$, moving around in $\mod n$ and then making sure you reverse the intial value only once in the $n$ function calls (using $\mod n$)?

Comment: This was exactly my approach! Nice work. I’m interested to see if there are more “natural” such functions $f$.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl Yes, that's exactly what's going on.

Comment: Small point: The first elements are $ε,0,1,00,01,10,11$ (you missed empty, 1-length, and all but one of the 2-length strings)

Comment: @charfellow None of those strings except $01$ are earlier than their reverses.

Comment: @f'' Aha, missed the part where you mention you're only using that set of strings. There is a related way to do this without taking those strings out, especially if you know n beforehand. That said, sorry for misreading!

Comment: ^vote with a follow-up question: How easy is it to determine *i* for a large *b*?

Comment: @hmmn Out of all the strings with length $x$, $2^{\left\lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\right\rceil}$ are palindromes. Out of the rest, half are $c$s and half are $d$s. Knowing this, you can figure out how many $i$s are used for each length.

Comment: @hmmn After that, to determine an index within the strings of length $x$, read the first $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor$ bits as an integer $a$. If $x$ is even, there are $a-1$ $c$s with the same starting bits; if $x$ is odd, there are $2(a-1)$. Beyond that, I don't actually know a good way to find $i$. :/